# SMTP Service crashes on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, service, smtp

on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine the SMTP service crashes without generate any event. I Set the service to restart when it fails but it doesn't.

How could I face this problem? Is a common issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please post relevant info from windows event log

Comment: smtpscv causes only warnings like:
Message Delivery to the host #IP failed while delivering to the remote domain #domainname# for the following reason: the connection was dropped by the remote host.
Is there a command or something like that to have only this service related issues? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the windows event log? Have you checked the smtp event log? There should be more information on the box somewhere, we can't help without that information.

Comment: In windows event log I can't find them.. Where can I find SMTP log?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear if your local mailer to win2008 connection is being reset or if win2008 to recipient domain connection is reset. If you cannot connect from your local PC to win2008 server, check if you are firewalled by your ISP on port 25.

`telnet smtp.gmail.com 25

Trying 74.125.141.108...

Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

220 mx.google.com ESMTP i4sm2686969pav.20`

If you don't see the above, you are blocked on port 25. If you see the above info, then may be your server IP is blacklisted and the recipient server is dropping the connection. Use a [blacklist checker](http://tools.vimmaniac.com) to check your IP.